# Digital Signature Authentication in java web application using USB token inserted at client pc

Tags: digital-signature

all
I'm Sumit , i'm working with Java based web application that needs two level of authentication first with username , password and second with user digital signature(stored on USB token) issued by CA.
So a java based web application that runs on server and it is accessible by client web browser. And web user insert his/her USB token at his/her PC to authenticate , so how a web application be able to  read public key from USB token and send it to server for further verification via browsers. Is there any javascript library that is used to do this?How a browser access USB token event and get public key from that USB token? Anyone have any idea or example please help me. I have been googling so much since last 15 days but not found any better solution for this.

Your help is appreciated very much.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Please refer to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757349/9659885  Signer.Digital extension is available for Windows, Linux and Mac

Answer (score 1):

Does the USB token is a smartcard type PKCS#11? Do you have a suitable driver for your operating system?

In this case you can configure server SSL / TLS connection requiring client authentication. For example, with Apache and mod_ssl using the directive
SSLVerifyClient require

Once the user connects to the https URL, the browser will request the user certificate, perform an electronic signature, and send it with also the public part of the certificate. In server you can get the content

You can't do this with javascript, because javascript is not allowed to access PC resources. In good times you could use Java, but now there is no support in Chrome, Edge or new versions of the JDK. And in other browsers is a challenge

Comment: can you please give more detail and more understating on this. I want to implement the same thing but have many question on that.

Comment: @CHiRAG, you can review https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html#allclients or https://www.openlogic.com/blog/mutual-authentication-using-apache-and-web-client

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so by using this I am able to read the client token certificate right?

Comment: Yes, Apache can send the electronic certificat. You need a specific connector for your application. For example mod_jk [https://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi] for tomcat

Comment: Do you have any example code to get an electronic certificate in java code. Actually, I have searched many things but didn't get any source to do the same